# My GCP MySQL 8 CloudSQL Database, Randomly Restarts without a clue

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mysql8

I using a mysql instance on cloud sql. However this instances began to restart the mysqld (mysql deamon) several times per day.

It was not due a change or anything, but just increasing like this.

every time the instance is restarted we lost near 1 minute of uptime

[image: Number of restart per day]

I didn't find any error or relevant log for sql instance before it's restarts it self.

What I already did:

- increase instance memory from 16 to 32gb (no effect)
- checked if there is a connection limit, is way below the limit.
- checked processor CPU. it's very low in any time.
- checked that memory is always at 95% (as expected from mysql)
- checked disk size has a lot of free space
- noticed that the deamon restars occurs based on the instance heavy load
- Checked all logs before deamon restart, but nothing was found.
- exported the server variables. (https://gist.github.com/daniel-dia/a3b18bb033e9c8a74135c11725d013db)

what should be happening to this? What can i do in order to find the solution

Comment: Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164798/google-cloud-sql-instance-infinite-loading-on-restart/42201633#42201633), It might be due to the server's deadlock timeout (600 seconds), which results in an unexpected restart.

Comment: Less than 1/2 of your global variables are posted.  
Additional DB information request, please. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.